# Is there a way of generating an ObjC header for a Swift API from the command line?

Tags: swift, objective-c

If I have a .swift file, Apple's documentation says I can use Xcode to create an ObjC wrapper header for it, so I can call it from other ObjC code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-swift-into-objective-c

But there's no way of automating something like that as part of an external build (I've also just found it clunky and unreliable). So is there a way of generating the wrapper from the command line, say with some xcodebuild or swiftc command?

Comment: Automating what exactly? The swift-objc header is a **generated** file, it doesn't require any manual input.

Comment: Automating the process of creating the header.

Comment: So far I haven't had to touch Xcode at all for my project. I can use clang to build objc libs, and swiftc to build swift libs, all of which I can do from a single build script. I don't even have an xcode project. Having to create an xcode project just to generate this header seems unnecessary, and I can't interact with the xcode UI from a build script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found this: https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-use-a-swift-library-in-c/

Looks like swiftc has a -emit-objc-header flag.